# Using high level assembly (HLA): sh: 1: hlaparse: not found

Tags: xubuntu

I was following section 3.2 of the [HLA reference book](https://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/HighLevelAsm/HLADoc/HLARef/HLARef_pdf/03_InstallingHLA.pdf) to install HLA. After completing all the steps to extract the downloaded tar file for HLA, I added the appropriate folders to the `.bashrc` file.

Typing `hla -?` correctly displays the HLA help text, but trying to compile the hla file `hla file_name` failed, giving the error:

```
sh: 1: hlaparse: not found
```

I use Xubuntu 22.04.2 but I believe this error is also applicable to Ubuntu 22.04.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

This command fixed the issue for me. Now, running `hla file_name` correctly compiles `file_name.hla`

Comment: For the future and for anyone else with this problem, chaining apt commands together with `&&` is not a good practice when you are having problems. It's safer to run commands separately so that you can audit the results of each command before running the next. Using `&&` will continue running the next command without giving you any opportunity to correct problems. Also, `dist-upgrade` can be destructive and should be used with caution. If this solved the problem, it's likely that the actual problem had more to do with other misconfigured software and not necessarily specific to this package.

Comment: @Nmath I don't think I agree with your comment because `&&` means run the right hand command only if the left hand command exited successfully, which is supposed to be safer than running commands separately if they depend on each other in some way. I'm sure you are aware of this, but your comment seems to misrepresent the situation a bit. Yes, one might want to inspect the output rather than relying on the exit code, but whether that will be safer than using `&&` or not depends on one's level of expertise...

Comment: That's certainly a fair criticism and maybe my comment is a bit heavy on the caution. Personally, I would prefer to inspect output at each step, especially in the context of there already being preexisting problems as well as the use of `dist-upgrade` which is more agressive than `upgrade`. My advice would be to run them separately in either of these situations, but that advice could certainly be considered opinion